# Visual Studio 2013 no C++ templates Modify install doesn't fix

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm forced to use Visual Studio 2013 for a class, and I need to use c++ within it. I have downloaded and installed VS 2013 Professional with Update 5, however there is no option to create a C++ project. I have already attempted to repair and modify the install to include c++. The checkbox for c++ is selected on this modify isntall screen, and it seems to go through the motions of adding the c++ requirements. However, C++ still doesn't show up as an option in new templates. I have already tried running 'devenv /installvstemplates" from the command line, that seemed to add some files to the directory but still no c++ support. Can anyone shed any light on this? Thank you for your time

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 10